# How to update Colour of Label in UICollectionViewCell when UIViewController Class's button is selected

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, uilabel, uicollectionviewcell

[UIView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MHnu.png)

How do I change the Colour of the label inside the UICollectionViewCell at the top (e.g. Q1) when Button below the TextField is selected?

I would only want the current question's label to change its text color
i.e. if user is on Question 1, when the button is selected it changes the Q1 Colour from Orange to White.

Please see attached Picture Above

I have used UIViewController as the delegate/datasource for the UICollectionView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating `UICollectionViewCell`/`UITableViewCell` is most preferable by calling
`collectionView.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath])`

I suppose you have a sequence of questions and some correct/wrong flags. So you should have button selection handler and cell composing method

```
@objc private func onSomeButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let questionNumber: Int = 999
    self.markAnswer(correct: true, atIndex: questionNumber)
    self.collectionView.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath(item: questionNumber, section: 0)])
}
```

And then this call will trigger to reload this cell

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: self.someDefaultRequseId, for: IndexPath)
    cell.label.textColor = self.isAnswerCorrect(at: indexPath.item) ? .white : .red
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Had been stuck for weeks and weeks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly about your situation you don't need scroll insdie your collection view and so you don't need reusability of cells. So you need a static structure. For this situation it's better to use `UITableView` with static cells. You can set `IBOutlet` for each cell and also each of elements inside your cells into your main View Controller. Then inside `TouchUpInside` Action of your specific button set color for your label.